# How to distribute updates to a premium plugin?

Tags: plugins, premium

I’d have thought there’d be several how-tos on this, but for the life of me I couldn’t find one.

So, I’ve made a plugin that’s gained some traction, and I’d like to expand its functionality in a premium version. Let’s say I have distribution and a payment platform set up outside of the WordPress ecosystem – how do I provide updates to subscribers? Do you still host on Wordpress.org with some sort of token validation per request?

Comment: No I don't think you can host on wordpress.org. You'll have to host updates on your own server. I thought I had seen code out there to do this but I can't find it now either. You can hook into the update_plugins process I'd think. I'd find a plugin for updating from github - there are a few out there - and copy how it does it.